# Error with adding subview: not in the window hierarchy

Tags: hierarchy, ibeacon

//added
I want to open subview after action didrangebeacons is on. But when it going there there is no any views on screen. Just this error message

Same previous questions but it not helped to my problem. I haven't got any storyboard or xib files, just clear programming.

BeaconViewController: 0x155eb5b0 on UINavigationController: 0x1559bfe0 whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

**AppDelegate.m:**

```
- (void) viewDidAppear {

}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

DebugLog(@"");

NSLog(@"good1");


//and then access the variable by appDelegate.variable
// Оповещение о том, что надо включить Bluetooth, через минут, через 10 минут, через 8 часов, через неделю
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(timerCalled) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:900 target:self selector:@selector(timerCalled) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:28800 target:self selector:@selector(timerCalled) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:604800 target:self selector:@selector(timerCalled) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
// Конец

//Set up Core Location Manager
self.coreLocation = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
_coreLocation.delegate = self;

// Load any previously registered notifications
[self loadNotificationRegions];

// Google Analytics
// Optional: automatically send uncaught exceptions to Google Analytics.
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
// Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
// Optional: set debug to YES for extra debugging information.
[GAI sharedInstance].debug = YES;
// Create tracker instance.
id <GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-42731391-1"];

// Check if the app needs to read the settings from file
NSString *transition = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"transitionStyle"];

// Note: this will not work for boolean values as noted by bpapa below.
// If you use booleans, you should use objectForKey above and check for null
if (!transition) {
    [self readFromSettingsFile];
}

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

// Override point for customization after application launch.
[[UIButton appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

// Remove the shadows of the bar
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];

// Set the bar translucent

NSLog(@"good - start uinavig");
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
navController.navigationBar.translucent = true;
NSLog(@"good - end uinavig");

// Background Color
if (IS_IOS_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7")) {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:NAVIGATIONS_VIEWS_BACKGROUND_COLOR];
} else {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:NAVIGATIONS_VIEWS_BACKGROUND_COLOR];
}

// Buttons Color
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255 / 255.0f green:255 / 255.0f blue:255 / 255.0f alpha:1]];

// Back button
if (IS_IOS_LESS_THAN(@"7")) {

    UIImage *buttonBack30 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_back.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 25, 0, 5)];
    UIImage *buttonBack24 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_back_landscape.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 25, 0, 5)];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonBack30 forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonBack24 forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -1.5) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -2.0) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
    NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [attributes setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:(255 / 255.0f) green:(255 / 255.0f) blue:(255 / 255.0f) alpha:1.0f] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
    [attributes setValue:[UIColor clearColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextShadowColor];
    [attributes setValue:[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0, 0.0)] forKey:UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset];
    [attributes setValue:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:16.0f] forKey:UITextAttributeFont];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

// Title Color and Font
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                      [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                      [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:17.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil]];

self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
navController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.viewController];
//
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

**and calling:**

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)beaconRegion
    {
    blabla

if(blabla)
                            {
                                NSLog(@"good - testing - 03.5");

                                BeaconViewController* room = [[BeaconViewController alloc] init];

                                [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:room
                                                                             animated:YES
                                                                           completion:nil];
                                                                          completion:nil];

                                region.helloMessage = @"привет";
                            }
```

**BeaconViewController.m**

```
#import "BeaconViewController.h"
#import "PageView.h"

@implementation BeaconViewController
{
    NSUInteger _numPages;
}



- (void) vidDidAppear {

}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _numPages = 2;

    self.pagingScrollView.previewInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 50.0);
    [self.pagingScrollView reloadPages];

    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = _numPages;

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [self.pagingScrollView didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Actions

- (IBAction)pageTurn
{
    [self.pagingScrollView selectPageAtIndex:self.pageControl.currentPage animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - View Controller Rotation

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self.pagingScrollView beforeRotation];
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self.pagingScrollView afterRotation];
}

#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)theScrollView
{
    self.pageControl.currentPage = [self.pagingScrollView indexOfSelectedPage];
    [self.pagingScrollView scrollViewDidScroll];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)theScrollView
{
    if ([self.pagingScrollView indexOfSelectedPage] == _numPages - 1)
    {
        _numPages++;
        [self.pagingScrollView reloadPages];
        self.pageControl.numberOfPages = _numPages;
    }
}



#pragma mark - MHPagingScrollViewDelegate

- (NSUInteger)numberOfPagesInPagingScrollView:(MHPagingScrollView *)pagingScrollView
{
    return _numPages;
}

- (UIView *)pagingScrollView:(MHPagingScrollView *)thePagingScrollView pageForIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    PageView *pageView = (PageView *)[thePagingScrollView dequeueReusablePage];
    if (pageView == nil)
        pageView = [[PageView alloc] init];

    [pageView setPageIndex:index];
    return pageView;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

replacing

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
```

with

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController...
```

might resolve the issue

on an unrelated note killing daisychaining like so
- (void) vidDidAppear {

}
is asking for trouble down the road, consider cleaning up your code. it's a mess
even by stackoverflow standards